# How to make objects be in the bottom of a scrollview

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a scrollview with a root view which is Linear Layout

at the bottom of the LinearLayout there is a button

I want it to scroll up with the scroll view, but when the view first appears on the screen
I want the button to be at the bottom of the view and it's not

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/default_side_margin"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/default_side_margin"
        android:orientation="vertical" >


        <include
            android:id="@+id/details"
            layout="@layout/layout_details"
             />

        <include
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            layout="@layout/layout_btn_next" />
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

the first included layout takes up only about half the screen

I want the button to scroll up with the layout , but be far enough from layout details to be on the bottom of the screen

Comment: I always wonder same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Didnt fully understand your question but you should try android:fillViewport=true on a scrollview, look here:
http://www.curious-creature.org/2010/08/15/scrollviews-handy-trick/

Comment: He means, suppose there is an image and a button in scroll view. IF the image is large enough that the person has to scroll to see it, thats fine. But if the image is small, he want the button to remain at the bottom of the view.

Comment: So my answer is exactly what she's looking for.

Comment: Unfortunately this does not solve my problem :(
i put android:fillViewport="true" on the scrollview tag, and the button still remained in the center of the screen when the content takes up half of the screen

Comment: my problem was not isolated to the scroll view viewport, i also needed to set the android:gravity="bottom" on the top container of the button that i was trying to include